# Esbuild package inside Angular has vulnerabilities

Tags: angular

I have updated Angular to its latest version 16.2.7 but Esbuild package inside angular-devkit/build-angular package has vulnerabilities. I can ignore those and deploy my project but my company has standard that code must be passed through Google scan so what should I do now? Below is the version info:

```
@angular-devkit/build-angular@16.2.7
  +-- esbuild@0.18.17
  `-- vite@4.4.7
    `-- esbuild@0.18.17 deduped
```

Google scanner says that if esbuild version is 0.19.5 then there is no vulnerabilities. I cannot update esbuild alone because it's a child package of angular-devkit/build-angular.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not a question but a library issue and should be raised there.

Comment: @NickFelker Its a whole google product(Angular) issue you can try it yourself just create fresh sample project of angular and scan it with google scanner you will find vulnerabilities in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try removing node_modules and your package-lock.json and running npm install again.

Comment: No brother google product(angular) is vulnerable their own scanner is showing vulnerabulities. I tried all these ways which you are suggesting you can  try yourself. please upvote so google will resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

Guys finally I found a solution for this but this should be resolve by Google itself. PFB below solution we can override the nested packages which are vulnerable so for this we need to add override flag inside package.json file PFB sample code also let me know if anyone knows how can we report bugs of google product. :-

```
"overrides": {
      "@angular-devkit/build-angular": {
        "esbuild": "0.19.5"
      }
  }
```